# Unexpected Result from PHP DOMXPath query

Tags: php, xpath

I've this structure of an xml-document:

```
<realestates:realEstates xmlns:ns2="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/platform/gis/1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:common="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/common/1.0" xmlns:realestates="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0">
  <realEstateList>
    <typeList>
      <realEstateElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:offerlistelement="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/listelement/1.0">
        <address>
          <postcode>31874</postcode>
        </address>
      </realEstateElement>
    </typeList>
  </realEstateList>
</realestates:realEstates>
```

Now I want to select all realEstateElement-elemets which are not starting i.e. with 31 in the postcode because I want to remove them from the document.

I try to select all matching with this xpath-expression

```
typeList//realEstateElement/address[starts-with(postcode,"31")]
```

But what I get ist nothing. If I remove typeList at the beginning, I get all matching postcode-elements and not the realEstateElement-elements. Has anybody an idea how I can remove all dismatching elements on a simple way?

Thanks!

Comment: Your root element is prefixed but you don't have an *xmlns:realestates="something"* declaration. Those headers are important. Include more of your source to show this. Your code should include the full tree to the elements you are interested in (at least the root or element where the `xmlns` is declared, the `<typelist>` element tree, and the one you posted in that context. XPath is all about context.

Comment: With or without the `typelist` selector, your XPath will always select an `<address>` node. You are *not* selecting `<realEstateElement>` or `<postcode>`. You are just using `<realEstateElement>` as part of the path to get to `<address>`, and `<postcode>` as part of the predicate to *restrict* the nodes.

Comment: Thank you! I've added the namespaces. How can I select realEstateElement instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
//realEstateElement/address[starts-with(postcode,"31")]
```

selects *all* the `address` nodes inside each descendant `realEstateElement` nodes. It's a XPath expresion with two steps. The *last* step is always the one you are selecting. The previous steps only create the *context* for the others. Each step can have one or more *predicates* which have the format `[` *boolean expression * `]`. Each selected node is compared to its predicate and only the ones that match it are kept in the context or in the final result.

So if you want to select the `realEstateElement` nodes that match your predicate, you need to have it as your *last* step. The rest of the path (`address/postcode`) can be used in the *predicate* which is in the *context* of the `realEstateElement` node:

```
//realEstateElement[starts-with(address/postcode,"31")]
```

This will return all `realEstateElement` nodes that contain an `address` element containing a `postcode` element with the text contents starting with `31`.

---

*Note 1*: You can add more predicates if you have to restrict the node further:

```
//realEstateElement[starts-with(address/postcode,"31")][not(starts-with(address‌​/postcode, "318"))]
```

This will select *from* the `realEstateElements` that have `address/postcode` starting with "31", all those which *do not* start with 318. The predicates are valid *in the context* created by the previous predicate or step.

---

*Note 2*: The namespaces would be important if you needed to include any one of them in your XPath, which so far doesn't seem to be the case. In case you need to do that, you will have to *register a prefix* so you can use the selector in an expression:

```
$xmldoc->registerXPathNamespace('re', 'http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0');
```

The prefix doesn't have to match the one declared in the document (which might not exist, if it is a default namespace). With this, you could use expressions like this one:

```
/re:realEstates/realEstateList/typeList/realEstateElement[starts-with(address/postcode,"31")]
```

which also selects `realEstateElement` using an absolute expression.

Comment: Thank you very much. But is there some 'not-start-with'?

Comment: I learn: //realEstateElement[not(starts-with(address/postcode, "318"))]

Comment: You can *add* that predicate if you have to restrict the node set you got back: `//realEstateElement[starts-with(address/postcode,"31")][not(starts-with(address/postcode, "318"))]`. This will select *from* the `realEstateElement`s that start with `31`, all that *do not* start with 318. Remember that the predicates are valid in the context created by the previous predicate or step.

Comment: Can I also use lower-case?

Comment: Case matters in XML. `Element` is not the same as `element`.

Comment: No, I mean for example <city>Hannover</city> And <city>hannover</city>. So i want to ignore lower or uppercase.

Comment: In XPath 2.0 you have the `lower-case()` function which you can use. In XPath 1.0 you have to rely on `translate()`. Assuming that you have something like `<city>Hannover</city>` and `<city>HANNOVER</city>` you can have a case insensitive selection with `city[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'hannover']`. This will *not* convert special or accented characters, unless you also add them to the translate list.